# Laravel yajra datatable is not loading the new filter data in the datatable properly

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

Laravel yajra data table is not loading the new filter data in the datatable,
it's loading correct on the server side, but not passing to the view, it's load the existing one again.

Output:
Total records image
[image]

Filtered record image
[image]

After filter it's load all the data again how can i avoid this
I found a solution but it's not going to work.

Blade code

```
 var table = $('#tickets-list').DataTable({
        processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('admin.timetable.index') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'student_id'},
                {data: 'day'},
                {data: 'subject'},
                {data: 'time'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]

    });

//Solution
    $('#family_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        table.draw();

    });
```

My controller code

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
                $timetables = TimeTable::all();
                return Datatables::of($timetables)
                            ->addIndexColumn()

                            ->filter(function ($instance) use ($request) {

                                if (!empty($request->get('family_id'))) {

                                    $instance->collection = $instance->collection->filter(function ($row) use ($request) {

                                        return Str::contains($row['family_id'], $request->get('family_id')) ? true : false;

                                    });

                                }
                            })   
                            
                            ->rawColumns(['action', 'id'])
                            ->make(true);
        }
            return view('auth.timetable.index', compact('timetables'));
```

Comment: What are you filtering? The table doesnt have a column family is?

Comment: @Collin Family_Id is there, have a look at console

Comment: Don't use a form to submit your filter data to the server. Use DataTables, by using its [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option. See the examples which use the function form, for example: `"data": function ( d ) { d.extra_search = $('#extra').val(); }`.